# how to access class this inside jquery callback es6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, es6-class

```
    events ( node ) {

        let thisclass = this;

        node.on('mouseover', ( d, i ) => {
            thisclass.animateParentChain( d );
        });

        node.on('mouseout', (d, i) => {
            d3.select(this).select("circle").attr("r", 2.5);
            thisclass.unAnimateParentChain( d );
        });

        node.on('click', (nd, i) => {
            thisclass.persistsAnimateParentChain( nd );
            thisclass.loadModal(nd);
        });
    }
```

The above is a method in an es6 class. The original script looked like this:

```
events: function ( node ) {
        node.on('mouseover', function ( d, i ) {
            app.radialD3.animateParentChain( d );
        });
        node.on('mouseout', function(d, i){
            d3.select(this).select("circle").attr("r", 2.5);
            app.radialD3.unAnimateParentChain( d );
        });
        node.on('click', function(nd, i){
            app.radialD3.persistsAnimateParentChain( nd );
            app.radialD3.loadModal(nd);
        });
    },
```

The new es6 method can be rewritten using the function keyword eg:

```
events ( node ) {

        let thisclass = this;

        node.on('mouseover', function ( d, i ) {
            thisclass.animateParentChain( d );
        });

        node.on('mouseout', function (d, i) {
            d3.select(this).select("circle").attr("r", 2.5);
            thisclass.unAnimateParentChain( d );
        });

        node.on('click', function(nd, i){
            thisclass.persistsAnimateParentChain( nd );
            thisclass.loadModal(nd);
        });
    }
```

Changing to use the function keyword and things work. Without, the script has issues with `this` keyword.

I am reasonably new to the es6 stuff, but what is the "proper" way of writing this. In the callback i need `this` to be the html element and not the class, but at the same time the callback needs to access methods of the class. Using the function keyword seems to be taking a step backward, as does setting the current class into a variable :/

How do you differentiate between the `this`'s ?

Comment: You can't have `this` refer to two different things at once, so yes you should use `function` and access the class instance through closure just as you did.

Comment: The "proper" way to do this would be to not need to use `this` to access the html element. Can't you also access it as `node`, `d`, `e.currentTarget` or something like that?

Comment: *"Using the function keyword seems to be taking a step backward"* Function expressions/declarations and arrow functions are two different tools. Arrow functions are not a (complete) replacement for the existing function definitions, so it's definitely not a step backwards. You have to to use the right tool for the job.